# How to set property of array so that by json_encode i will get desired result

Tags: javascript, php

**Expected Output**

```
['#ff0000','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#00bcd4','#00bcd4','#4caf50','#4caf50']
```

i am getting follwing output

```
["'#ff0000','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#00bcd4'","'#00bcd4','#4caf50','#4caf'"]
```

***this is my code***

```
$color_str=Array
(
    [0] => '#ff0000'
    [1] => '#4caf50'
    [2] => '#4caf50'
    [3] => '#4caf50'
    [4] => '#00bcd4'
)
$color_string=json_encode($color_str);
```

Comment: What you are looking for is not a valid json

Comment: The output has 8 entries while your array has 5. Why? As @Sunil pointed out, the expected result is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
['#ff0000','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#00bcd4','#00bcd4','#4caf50','#4caf50']
```

is not valid JSON because JSON uses " instead of '.

Define you Array like this

```
$color_str=Array('#ff0000','#4caf50','#4caf50','#4caf50','#00bcd4');
```

and the resulting JSON will be

```
["#ff0000","#4caf50","#4caf50","#4caf50","#00bcd4"]
```